# I want to return back a Arraylist of string which contains userName in the response with the response code 200

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, httpresponse

I want to return back a Arraylist of string which contains userName in the response with the response code 200. How to implement this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using Springboot, look up RestTemplate and @RestController. That may take you closer to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ResponseEntity<List<String>> someMethod() {
   List<String> userNames = getvalues();
   return new ResponseEntity<>(userNames, OK);
}
```